# Is it OK to make a placement new on memory managed by a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, smart-pointers, undefined-behavior

### Context

For test purpose, I need to construct an object on non-zero memory. This could be done with:

```
{
    struct Type { /* IRL not empty */};
    std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(Type)> non_zero_memory;
    non_zero_memory.fill(0xC5);
    auto const& t = *new(non_zero_memory.data()) Type;
    // t refers to a valid Type whose initialization has completed.
    t.~Type();
}
```

Since this is tedious and made multiple times, I'd like to provide a function returning a smart pointer to such a `Type` instance. I came up with the following, but I fear undefined behavior lurk somewhere.

### Question

Is the following program well defined? Especially, is the fact that a `std::byte[]` has been allocated but a `Type` of equivalent size is freed an issue?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

auto non_zero_memory(std::size_t size)
{
    constexpr std::byte non_zero = static_cast<std::byte>(0xC5);

    auto memory = std::make_unique<std::byte[]>(size);
    std::fill(memory.get(), memory.get()+size, non_zero);
    return memory;
}

template <class T>
auto on_non_zero_memory()
{
    auto memory = non_zero_memory(sizeof(T));
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new (memory.release()) T());
}    

int main()
{
    struct Type { unsigned value = 0; ~Type() {} }; // could be something else
    auto t = on_non_zero_memory<Type>();
    return t->value;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eba88eefafbf380a)

Comment: There are rules about objects replacing other objects, and rules about trivial objects not needing explicit destruction - I'll let someone find the proper wording to prove you're safe though

Comment: The memory isn't really managed by a smart pointer since you `release`d it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux only to let it be managed by another smart pointer though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `Type` is not necessarily that simple. Let me correct that... Q fixed.

Comment: @YSC Seems reasonable. Though I don't see what using a `unique_ptr` in the first place changes to the question. I only ask because it's part of the question title so I'm assuming it's meant to be an important part of the question.

Comment: @YSC: It's more about what `std::byte` is

Comment: I think this boils down to: Is it OK to delete reused memory directly instead of explicit destructor call, then delete using the original pointer type. Smart pointer is only relevant in sense that it does the former by default. In case of shared_ptr, it would be trivial to use a custom deleter if it turned out that the code in question was UB.

Comment: If `T`'s constructor throws you will leak memory

Comment: @virgesmith Absolutely, it's worth an answer, especially if you have a solution.

Comment: @YSC You could placement `new` on `memory.get()` and then `release` if the construction of `T` doesn't fail in the next statement.

Comment: Have you considered [overriding `T`'s `new` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Class-specific_overloads) to write over the storage instead?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No I didn't until now. It's only good if `T` is a type I write though?

Comment: @YSC It's a bit more intrusive, so it may not be applicable for your situation but it's significantly simpler to implement, easier to understand and unquestionably well defined behavior.

Comment: The first code snippet is generally incorrect, since you do not care proper alignment for objects of type `Type`. Better to use `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Type), alignof(Type)>` than `std::array` of chars.

Comment: Could you use the `shared_ptr` constructor with a custom deleter type - something like `shared_ptr { casted_buf_ptr, [buf = std::move(buf), casted_buf_ptr] { casted_buf_ptr->~T(); /* buf.release(); */ } }`

Comment: Formally speaking, nothing you previously wrote into the storage remains after the placement new; it effectively clobbers the entire storage occupied by the created object. At least one major implementation is known to rely on this rule to optimize away the fill as a dead store.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "_rules about trivial objects not needing explicit destruction_" when do you **need** explicit destruction?

Comment: @curiousguy When the objects you're replacing aren't trivially-destructible

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What happens when you omit the explicit destruction? (appart from a memory leak if a resource was managed)

Comment: @curiousguy Undefined behaviour, if memory serves.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This program is not well defined.

The rule is that if a type has a [trivial destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible) (See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Storage_reuse)), you don't need to call it. So, this:

```
return std::shared_ptr<T>(new (memory.release()) T());
```

is *almost* correct. It omits the destructor of the `sizeof(T)` `std::byte`s, which is fine, constructs a new `T` in the memory, which is fine, and then when the `shared_ptr` is ready to delete, it calls `delete this->get();`, which is wrong. That first deconstructs a `T`, but then it deallocates a `T` instead of a `std::byte[]`, which will *probably* (undefined) not work.

C++ standard §8.5.2.4p8 [expr.new]

> A new-expression may obtain storage for the object by calling an allocation function. [...] If the allocated type is an array type, the allocation function's name is `operator new[]`.

(All those "may"s are because implementations are allowed to merge adjacent new expressions and only call `operator new[]` for one of them, but this isn't the case as `new` only happens once (In `make_unique`))

And part 11 of the same section:

> When a new-expression calls an allocation function and that allocation has not been extended, the new-expression passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first argument of type `std::size_t`. That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; it may be greater than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array. For arrays of `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte`, the difference between the result of the new-expression and the address returned by the
>   allocation function shall be an integral multiple of the strictest fundamental alignment requirement (6.6.5) of any object type whose size is no greater than the size of the array being created. [Note: Because allocation
>   functions are assumed to return pointers to storage that is appropriately aligned for objects of any type with fundamental alignment, this constraint on array allocation overhead permits the common idiom of allocating
>   character arrays into which objects of other types will later be placed. — end note ]

If you read §21.6.2 [new.delete.array], you see that the default `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]` do the exact same things as `operator new` and `operator delete`, the problem is we don't know the size passed to it, and it is *probably* more than what `delete ((T*) object)` calls (to store the size).

Looking at what delete-expressions do:

§8.5.2.5p8 [expr.delete]

> [...] delete-expression will invoke the destructor (if any) for [...] the elements of the array being deleted

p7.1

> If the allocation call for the new-expression for the object to be deleted was not omitted [...], the delete-expression shall call a deallocation function (6.6.4.4.2). The value returned from the allocation call of the new-expression shall be passed as the first argument to the deallocation function.

Since `std::byte` does not have a destructor, we can safely call `delete[]`, as it will not do anything other than call the deallocate function (`operator delete[]`). We just have to reinterpret it back to `std::byte*`, and we will get back what `new[]` returned.

Another problem is that there is a memory leak if the constructor of `T` throws. A simple fix is to placement `new` while the memory is still owned by the `std::unique_ptr`, so even if it does throw it will call `delete[]` properly.

```
T* ptr = new (memory.get()) T();
memory.release();
return std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, [](T* ptr) {
    ptr->~T();
    delete[] reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(ptr);
});
```

The first placement `new` ends the lifetime of the `sizeof(T)` `std::byte`s and starts the lifetime of a new `T` object at the same address, as according to §6.6.3p5 [basic.life]

> A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies or by explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor. [...]

Then when it is being deleted, the lifetime of `T` ends by an explicit call of the destructor, and then according to the above, the delete-expression deallocates the storage.

---

This leads to the question of:

What if the storage class wasn't `std::byte`, and was not trivially destructible? Like, for example, we were using a non-trivial union as the storage.

Calling `delete[] reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr)` would call the destructor on something that is not an object. This is clearly undefined behaviour, and is according to §6.6.3p6 [basic.life]

> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated [...], any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or
>   was located may be used but only in limited ways. [...] The program has undefined behavior if: the object will be or was of a class type with a non-trivial destructor and the pointer is used as the operand of a delete-expression

So to use it like above, we have to construct it just to destruct it again.

The default constructor probably works fine. The usual semantics are "create an object that can be destructed", which is exactly what we want. Use [`std::uninitialized_default_construct_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_default_construct_n) to construct them all to then immediately destruct them:

```
    // Assuming we called `new StorageClass[n]` to allocate
    ptr->~T();
    auto* as_storage = reinterpret_cast<StorageClass*>(ptr);
    std::uninitialized_default_construct_n(as_storage, n);
    delete[] as_storage;
```

We can also call `operator new` and `operator delete` ourselves:

```
static void byte_deleter(std::byte* ptr) {
    return ::operator delete(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr));
}

auto non_zero_memory(std::size_t size)
{
    constexpr std::byte non_zero = static_cast<std::byte>(0xC5);

    auto memory = std::unique_ptr<std::byte, void(*)(std::byte*)>(
        reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(::operator new(size)),
        &::byte_deleter
    );
    std::fill(memory.get(), memory.get()+size, non_zero);
    return memory;
}

template <class T>
auto on_non_zero_memory()
{
    auto memory = non_zero_memory(sizeof(T));
    T* ptr = new (memory.get()) T();
    memory.release();
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, [](T* ptr) {
        ptr->~T();
        ::operator delete(ptr, sizeof(T));
                            // ^~~~~~~~~ optional
    });
}
```

But this looks a lot like `std::malloc` and `std::free`.

A third solution might be to use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) as the type given to `new`, and have the deleter work as with `std::byte` because the aligned storage is a trivial aggregate.

Comment: Alignment is only needed for over-aligned types though.

Comment: @eerorika I thought it was UB to access (e.g) an `int` with alignment of 4 if it was not on a 4-byte boundary?

Comment: I'm not sure `delete[] reinterpret_cast<byte*>(ptr);` is allowed (not sure it's not either). There is no longer an `std::byte[]` at `ptr` since it was replaced by a placement `new`. Consider the case where it was an array of a non-trivial type. Assuming you had called the destructors before the placement `new` as you should, you would now be calling those destructors again. Is there an exemption or special rule that allows this for trivial types?

Comment: @Artyer It is. `new[]` (and thus `std::make_unique`) align to `alignof(std::max_align_t)`. No need to align again any types that don't require higher alignment,

Comment: Since this is a language lawyer question, it would be nice to have some form of authoritative source backing up the claims made.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is legal.  see cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, in that case, it would call the destructor twice and not be allowed, but you are allowed to call the destructor twice when it is trivial (as it does nothing). I'll look up a source on that.

Comment: @eerorika I didn't know that. I removed it

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay, seems pretty straight forward. And I guess if the original memory was an array of non-trivial types, you could do as eerorika suggests and placement `new` the original array elements before the `delete[]`.

Comment: @Artyer check [virgesmith's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095233/is-it-ok-to-make-a-placement-new-on-memory-managed-by-a-smart-pointer/54095531?noredirect=1#comment95023921_54095233) on the question. I would suggest fixing the exception safety in your answer for a complete example. François's comment after it has the solution.

Comment: Interesting that it's not only trivial types that don't need to have their destructor called, but it's okay with anything that doesn't depend on what that destructor does.

Comment: Your fix for the leak is UB. You must assign the result of the `new` to the `shared_ptr`'s constructor. This will probably work but is, strictly speaking, undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no destructor for `std::byte` so no non static member is being called.  `std::byte` is defined as `enum class byte : unsigned char {} ;` so it is just a `char`

Comment: @Artyer edit by edit you're going to what could become an excellent answer. If you do, be reassured you'll get a nice bounty. I'm telling you that to encourage you to rework this answer to (1) go directly for an answer (yes/no) + a reason (quote) + a solution; and (2) mention the alignment and exception (done) issue. The Q is eligible for a bounty in ~48h, but it's still fresh in your mind right now.

Answer (score 15):

```
std::shared_ptr<T>(new (memory.release()) T())
```

Is undefined behavior.  The memory that was acquired by `memory` was for a `std::byte[]` but  the `shared_ptr`'s deleter is doing to call `delete` on a pointer to `T`.  Since the pointer no longer has the same type you can't call delete on it per [[expr.delete]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.delete#2)

> In a single-object delete expression, the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject representing a base class of such an object. If not, the behavior is undefined.

You would have to provide the `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that destroys `T` and then casts the pointer back to its source type and call `delete[]` on that.

---

It should also be noted that `new (memory.release()) T()` itself will be undefined if `memory` allocated a type that has non trivial destruction.  You would have to call the destructor on the pointer from `memory.release()` first before you reuse it's memory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186385/discussion-on-answer-by-nathanoliver-is-it-ok-to-make-a-placement-new-on-memory).