Delete casted pointer basic type
I have seen this code in an open source project:
void EXPORT_API ReleaseDracoData(DracoData **data_ptr) {
  if (!data_ptr) {
    return;
  }
  const DracoData *const data = *data_ptr;
  switch (data->data_type) {
    case draco::DataType::DT_INT8:
      delete[] static_cast<int8_t *>(data->data);
      break;
    case draco::DataType::DT_UINT8:
      delete[] static_cast<uint8_t *>(data->data);
      break;
    case draco::DataType::DT_INT16:
      delete[] static_cast<int16_t *>(data->data);
      break;
    case draco::DataType::DT_UINT16:
      delete[] static_cast<uint16_t *>(data->data);
      break;
    case draco::DataType::DT_INT32:
      delete[] static_cast<int32_t *>(data->data);
      break;
    case draco::DataType::DT_UINT32:
      delete[] static_cast<uint32_t *>(data->data);
      break;
    case draco::DataType::DT_FLOAT32:
      delete[] static_cast<float *>(data->data);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  delete data;
  *data_ptr = nullptr;
}

I was wondering, since these are just basic numeric types, and no destructor needs to be called, can we avoid doing the switch?
void EXPORT_API ReleaseDracoData(DracoData **data_ptr) {
  if (!data_ptr) {
    return;
  }
  const DracoData *const data = *data_ptr;
  delete[] static_cast<int8_t *>(data->data);
  delete data;
  *data_ptr = nullptr;
}


"No destructor needs to be called" is not a criterion for well-defined behaviour.

The documentation for delete[] says that the type of the allocated array and the type passed to delete[] must be "similar". Which is, for the purposes of this question, "the same type, modulo cv qualifiers". Otherwise you get undefined behavior. Note that the compiler is free to flatten that switch-case to a single delete[] call, but not you as a programmer.

I had a similar question a few years back. The answer is no. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095233/is-it-ok-to-make-a-placement-new-on-memory-managed-by-a-smart-pointer and especially the reason for the answer which would be similar to yours.

@Botje Thanks, I found the documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Similar_types

Use malloc and free, or operator new and operator delete functions. No switch! Though I would rather try writing DracoData in idiomatic C++.

Not a directly related answer, as you are referring to an open source project, but the switch/cast construct above might also be done with a C++17 std::variant and a templated visitor, which basically means that you need only one (templated) delete function. Looks nicer, but generates similar code internally.

Thanks, all for the comments.
As a summary, the answer is, unfortunately, NO.
Documentation for delete[] ptr from cppreference (emphasize mine):

ptr must be a null pointer or a pointer whose value is previously
obtained by an array form of new-expression whose allocation function
was not a non-allocating form (i.e. overload (10)).  The pointed-to
type of ptr must be similar to the element type of the array
object. If ptr is anything else, including if it is a pointer obtained
by the non-array form of new-expression, the behavior is undefined.

So this would only work if the types are similar, which isn't the case.

cppreference is a very good reference, it is a documentation, but it s not "the documentation". It can contain errors (not in this case).

As a side note, when I see a switch on a "type" indicator, I'm almost always certain that there should be virtual inheritance or templates, or both, instead. Likewise, I don't think I've ever used new[] (I prefer vectors or arrays instead), and I certainly don't like seeing delete statements...
