Is GCC right with -Wuninitialized?
Let's consider the following code (Compiler Explorer):
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>

struct Data
{
    //Data() {} // TODO
    int value;
};

auto test()
{
    alignas(Data) std::array<std::byte, sizeof(Data)> buffer;
    buffer.fill(std::byte{0xFF});
    auto* const p = new(buffer.data()) Data;
    const auto value = p->value;
    p->~Data();
    return value;
}

What I would expect from this code is that:

A correctly aligned buffer of sizeof(Data) bytes is created and filled with 0xFF.
Data is constructed in it without initializing any value.
Hence, it retains the original memory of the buffer itself.
And so, under typical circumstances -1 is returned from test.

Judging from the generated assembly on Compiler Explorer all three compilers:

GCC (as in the link above),
Clang,
MSVC,

indeed, do so. In the examples I took newest compiler versions and C++17 but if language version matters here, I'm eager to hear.

Now, if we uncomment the empty Data constructor (Compiler Explorer):
Data() {} // TODO

Nothing changes for

Clang
MSVC

but for GCC we get -Wuninitialized warning and the generated code returns now 0 (rather than -1) which looks like the compiler considers this Undefined Behavior and just did whatever.
Is GCC correct in considering this (I presume) Undefined Behavior and issuing -Wuninitialized? Or is Clang and MSVC correct in considering this OK?

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095233/is-it-ok-to-make-a-placement-new-on-memory-managed-by-a-smart-pointer

Language version does matter, for these corner cases.

You might initialize the underlying memory, but you don't actually initialize the variable itself. Even if it's known, the value of value will still be indeterminate and using it will lead to undefined behavior.

And all three compilers are correct in the sense that accessing a non initialised object (p->value) is undefined behaviour, no diagnostic required.

"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash." Consistency of undefined behavior for a fixed compiler

It's curious that the explicit constructor changes the diagnostics though, because without it you'd still get a default constructor behaving just the same (not initializing the members).

@Lundin Data() = default;: no warning. Warnings are black magic ^^

@YSC Yeah that would be the same as omitting the constructor entirely. My point is that warnings should behave consistently. This is probably something language-lawyer thing where the class is no longer considered an "aggregate" in one case of the other. I'll pass on that - the language is a mess here.

Not entirely, I think this is not related to the language but rather to the individual implementation. Even if defaulted, a defined constructor is a user-defined constructor, which makes the class not an aggregate. See https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1.1

Formally, when you create a new object, its value is initially always indeterminate (before C++26). It doesn't matter whether the memory where the new object is placed already had some bytes written to it beforehand.
So in p->value the value of value is indeterminate, because p refers to a new Data object that you created in the previous line. Whatever you did with that memory at that location previously doesn't matter. Reading the indeterminate value of type int causes undefined behavior.
Whether or not you define the default constructor doesn't matter either. It doesn't initialize or modify the member value with another value either way.
What you want to do here requires std::start_lifetime_as:
auto* const p = std::start_lifetime_as<Data>(&buffer);


Well, it is odd though that GCC issues warning with Data() {} and doesn't without it... As others explained, the warning is optional, hence, this is valid. Yet odd. :) start_lifetime_as seems promising, but this is C++23. Thanks!

It appears the fundamental problem here is your assumption in step 3. C++ specifically bans the reading of a value that was not written before - this is what -WUninitialized tries to detect.
Specifically, that value must have the right type, and the object containing the value must be continuously alive between writing and reading.
Your example fails both the "right type" and "continuously alive".
Since warnings are entirely optional, GCC is right, and so are Clang and MSVC. They don't "consider it OK", but they don't warn either.

My understanding was that since I explicitly set the content of the buffer then the memory is initialized. It has a very well-known content that can be (and is) calculated at compile time, what you can see by playing with the initial 0xFF. However, now I realize that by this definition it would never be "uninitialized" since the memory always has some value. And the difference between "has the content I intended" and "has random trash" is not so clear really...

@AdamBadura it is anyway type-punning between std::array<std::byte, X> and Data ... through sharing memory location. That is said to be undefined behavior. So compiler is not required to even compile it,  if it does then it is not said what code it has to generate, also it is not required nor forbidden to diagnose it. So gcc behaves within those limits.

@AdamBadura: even the idea that "memory always has a value" isn't true in C++, or even on modern computers. "Page not present" is a common CPU exception when memory doesn't have any value. And with caches and threads, the notion of a value also imposes a false upper limit of 1.

@ÖöTiib My original reason was that there was a need for explicitly uninitialized values (which are later set to something by flow logic). While I'm skeptical and safeness of this, the request was an interesting idea. I have developed this but needed to test it and here is where I tried to use the "clever" trick with the buffer, but GCC kept acting as if it was initializing to 0 anyway. And investigating it deeper and deeper lead me to narrow down the problem and formulate the question as this again became an interesting problem of its own.

@AdamBadura so you try to build your own MSan? But such things have to be built in cooperation with compiler authors ... nothing to do.

@AdamBadura: "Explicity uninitialized" is already supported in C++, that's just an empty std::optional<T>.

@MSalters, yeah, but this adds an extra bool. If used for uint64_t then also extra 7 bytes of padding. But it does also provide extra safety checks (or at least a possibility of using them).

It is undefined behavior as reading uninitialized values is undefined behavior. There is a proposal to change that for variables with automatic storage duration, which is accepted for c++26. But that change doesn't affect this situation.
Since it's UB, the compilers are not required to give you a warning or any other kind of diagnostic. So your compilers are not actually disagreeing and all correct. GCC is just more helpful by warning you about the UB.
To be clear: You writing some content to the memory before constructing the object there does in no way replace initialization. Reading that memory via the object is still UB.
